# Cocos2D-X for android, Symbol 'cocos2d' could not be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I start with Cocos2D-X for android following http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started.

I run the demo in xcode and android with no problem, until I go to the **'
Defining a Combined Java/C++ Project in Eclipse'** part.

After I do all in this, I get the error `Symbol 'cocos2d' could not be resolved` for `using namespace cocos2d;` in `jni/hellocpp/main.cpp` and many other similar errors. And I find `#include "cocos2d.h"` missing in this file, so I add this line, but the error still exists.

I don't why, but I think it must be some libraries not be imported.

In my android project, there is a `includes` dir including NDK and $(COCOS2DX_HOME)/cocos2dx/include, but in $(COCOS2DX_HOME)/cocos2dx/include there are only 7 .h files(include cocos2d.h). I don't know if this is correct.

Does anybody can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have solved this problem according to another  article (http://www.cnblogs.com/young40/archive/2012/10/19/cocos2d-x-mac-os-x-android-xcode-ios-development-setup.html written by Chinese).

The important differences between http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started, I list below:

1. right click project, and select Properties\C/C++ General\Paths and Symbols\Source location. Click Link Folder, check the Link to a folder in the file system checkbox, and browse to the **cocos2dx** directory inside the **$COCOS2DX_HOME** folder.( the same way as add Classes)
2. right click project and select Properties\C/C++ General\Path and Symbols\GNU C++. Add `$(COCOS2DX_HOME)/CocosDenshion/include`

At first, I doubted not including `cocos2dx` class. And actually after I linked `$COCOS2DX_HOME/cocos2dx` into project, all wrongs gone away.

Comment: I don't have "C/C++ General" item in the properties. Don't you know why? :) I've imported built game in the Eclipse but have two errors: "Cocos2dxActivity cannot be resolved to a type" and "The import org.cocos2dx.lib cannot be resolved".

Comment: @JavaRunner do you import the related project in `cocos2dx/platform/android/java`

Comment: @JavaRunner for why you don't have "C/C++ General" item, have you already install CDT plugins?

Comment: thanks! I've just imported cocos2dx/platform/android/java and it works now! :)

Comment: I tried all your suggestions on Windows 7 machine but I still have the same error. I don't quite understand what you meant in 1. of the list. When I browse to cocos2dx I got an error "The folder 'cocos2dx' already exists. Therefore, it could not be right. Any further tips to get cocos2d-2.0-rc2-x-2.0.1 running on Windows 7?

Answer (score 3):

Just check if you have included the path to Cocos2d-x headers folder in your project properties? 
If not right click on your project -> Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes tab -> Assembly -> Add -> PATH_TO_YOUR_COCOS2DX/cocos2dx/include
and also in GNU C++ tab

where you must replace PATH_TO_YOUR_COCOS2DX by the actual absolute path to where you  downloaded the cocos2dx

Comment: @pktangyue : Check your build_native.sh inside proj.android ...change the path of ndk and cocos2d-x source inside it